# need advice about bar charts

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I managed to remove the boundaries but the scale indicators are still persists. Can you help me what do you call the indicators highlighted in the circle. How to get rid of these without losing the labels for both the x-axis and y-axis [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTXaN.png)

Comment: @BigBen Those answers remove both the xticks and their labels. To remove the ticks but not the ticklabels, something like `plt.tick_params(...., length=0)` should work. [Hide ticks but show labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988241/python-hide-ticks-but-show-tick-labels)

Comment: @JohanC - yep, whoops should have read the question more carefully... in any case still a dupe.

Comment: Thanks JohanC and BigBen! I managed to suppress the tickers alone now.