# How do I remove the tick lines from the following graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science, visualization

Here is the code I have written:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('dowjones')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
plot = sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date', y='Price')

for ind, label in enumerate(plot.get_xticklabels()):
if ind % 200 == 0:
    label.set_visible(True)
else:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

Here is the graph it creates:
[image]

The above code only removed only the labels but not the ticks itself.
How do I remove the lines?

Comment: If you want to completely remove them: [`ax.set_xticks([])`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html). Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824309/7789963) also.

Comment: You seem to running very old seaborn/pandas/matplotlib versions.  In the new versions the dates are automatically converted to pandas datetime format, and matplotlib automatically sets appropriate ticks. Also note that, if you already created the `ax`, it is recommended to pass it as a parameter to the seaborn function (`sns.lineplot(..., ax=ax)`), and directly use `ax.get_xticklabels()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python hide ticks but show tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988241/python-hide-ticks-but-show-tick-labels)